# A Shifted Mellin Transform Or Half Moments from a Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions, mellin-transform

I've asked this question in two ways, as I think either is a solution to my problem. Assume that I have some distribution $f(t)$ for which I know the Mellin Transform $M(s)$ and the Laplace transform $L(p)$.

I am trying to find "half moments", i.e. $k \in -3/2, -1/2, 1/2, \cdots$, (or arbitrary moments, if that's easier) of a shift in the distribution, i.e.

$$E(t^s f(t-a)) \equiv \int_a^\infty t^s f(t-a)dt$$

I'm not sure if there is a simple formula for a "shifted" Mellin transform (which would be exactly what I need) or whether there is a way to derive "half" or arbitrary moments from the shifted Laplace, i.e. $e^{-a} L(p)$, as I know we can derive "normal" moments, i.e. $s \in N$, by taking the derivative.

Comment: Binomial theorem?

Comment: in general you cannot get anything better than $(t+a)^s = t^s \sum_k {a \choose k} (a/t)^k$ hence if everything converges (not sure it happens often) $\int_a^\infty t^s f(t-a) dt = \int_0^\infty (t+a)^s f(t) dt = \sum_k {a \choose k} a^k M(s-k)$

Comment: Thanks! The binomial series is a really helpful suggestion. Regarding convergence, I know that $M(s)$ is defined and finite for all $s$, so I might get lucky...